# Finding the nature of a series of complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, absolute-convergence

I'm trying to find the nature of this series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2+2i)}{e^{ni}n\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}}$$ but I don't know which test should I use.

Comment: It seems that $i$ is only the dummy index of summation, not the unit imaginary number.

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Comment: so sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the series is$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2+2i}{e^{in}n\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}},$$it converges absolutely, since$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\left\lvert\frac{2+2i}{e^{in}n\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}}\right\rvert=\frac{2\sqrt2}{n\sqrt[3]{n^2+1}}\leqslant\frac{2\sqrt2}{n^{5/3}}.$$

Comment: Muito obrigado!